# game-package-manager quake 2 install

Tags: games

On a lubuntu 16.04 xenial machine I'd like to install quake2, more for test than anything.
And then I'd like to install a quake 2 server, but first things first:
I've copied from my windows partition to my lubuntu desktop the old quake 2 game folder, from a windows install.
So on the desktop I have a Quake2 folder, and inside there are: baseq2, rogue, xatrix subfolders.
I've installed quake2 binaries with apt: apt-get install quake2

> What I'm trying to do is figure out how to have game-package-manager
>   make the relative deb files for the full quake2 (baseq2), the
>   reckoning (rogue), ground zero (xatrix).

Has anyone done it successfully, or does anyone knows the syntax for that?

Comment: I did it but it was a long time ago. I remember having trouble with the expansion packs -  I think I asked a question on this site about it. AFK now but will check shortly.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man6/game-data-packager.6.html, tried to put quake folder in this folder too ~/.steam/SteamApps/common/<game>/ but running game-package-manager quake2 always try to download files for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this on a virtual Lubuntu machine and it worked.

`sudo apt install quake2 game-data-packager`

`game-data-packager quake2 --package quake2-full-data /home/[redacted]/q2/baseq2`

This generated "/home/[redacted]/quake2-full-data_44_all.deb" - it did download some stuff, as you mentioned in a comment.

Installed that with `gdebi` and the game started up fine with `/usr/games/quake2`

For the expansion packs

`game-data-packager quake2 --package quake2-groundzero-data /home/[redacted]/q2/rogue`

creates quake2-groundzero-data_2.02+44_i386.deb, install this, run with `/usr/games/quake2 +set game rogue`

`game-data-packager quake2 --package quake2-reckoning-data /home/[redacted]/q2/xatrix`

creates quake2-reckoning-data_2.03+44_i386.deb, install this, run with `/usr/games/quake2 +set game xatrix`

Comment: wonderfull, that's the answer. mission packs were a bonus. you're a saint, and I really found it hard to understand such a simple syntax, shame on me.

Comment: Thanks! Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, so future questioners will know that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> game-package-manager quake2 always try to download files for me

That's a bit vague. It could be downloading the Demo version because it couldn't locate the full game.

Or donwloading "q2-314-demo-x86.exe" anyway even if you have the full game; because you have lost some/all of the HTML doc files along the time. (these will be installed in /usr/share/doc/quake2/).

So using "--package" it's the best way to tell GDP explicitely what you want.

The ~/.steam/... thing is only for games downloaded with (wine +) Steam
or steamcmd. Just specify the right path as an argument to GDP command
(or '.' for current directory) and it will scan the subdirectories from there.